# How do I use twitter-text in a browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I want to count tweet length. Twitter makes this very very hard.

They have this repo: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text which contains this folder: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/js which supposedly supports javascript.

When I try to use the script from a cdn like this: https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/twitter-text

it says `require is not defined`

I don't understand what I'm supposed to do. Why is it using require if it's for javascript?

Comment: because its designed for node.js, while you're trying to use it from a browser.

Comment: I do not think you can use the script like that. Follow their instructions.

Comment: You'll need to use a module bundler (webpack? rollup? I'm not sure what the JS ecosystem uses these days...) to compile your code for the browser.

Comment: `js/pkg/twitter-text-3.1.0.js` might work without needing a bundler or npm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install Browserify
2. Download the latest twitter-text script from this folder: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/js/pkg
3. Create `index.js` with the contents: `window.twitter = require('./twitter-text-3.1.0.min.js');`
4. Run `browserify index.js -o twitter-text-js.js`

The output file can now be run in browser and accessed with the global `twitter`.

(or just download the prepackaged version here: https://gist.github.com/skeddles/3841236279efebf053dfa39dfdbae2c2#file-twitter-text-js-js)